# GitHub or BitBucketのプライベートリポジトリから認証なしでJavascriptをHTMLからロードする方法

Tags: javascript, html, github, bitbucket

## 目的

Webアプリのヘッダーでjsソースを読み込むためです。

自前サーバーは持っておらず、ソース管理を GitHub or Bitbucket のプライベートリポジトリで行っているので直接ダウンロードしたいです。
（一人趣味開発時に頻繁にソース変更があるので）

検索してもこのような事例がほとんどありませんでしたので困っていました。
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願いいたします。

## やったこと

- `https://＜TOKEN＞:x-oauth-basic@github.com/＜USER_NAME＞/＜REPOSITORY＞/raw/master/＜FILE_NAME＞`
- `https://＜TOKEN＞@github.com/＜USER_NAME＞/＜REPOSITORY＞/raw/master/＜FILE_NAME＞`
- `https://＜TOKEN＞:x-oauth-basic@raw.githubusercontent.com/＜USER_NAME＞/＜REPOSITORY＞/master/＜FILE_NAME＞`
- `https://＜TOKEN＞@raw.githubusercontent.com/＜USER_NAME＞/＜REPOSITORY＞/master/＜FILE_NAME＞`
- `https://＜TOKEN＞:＜USER_ID＞@github.com/＜USER_NAME＞/＜REPOSITORY＞/raw/master/＜FILE_NAME＞`
- `https://＜TOKEN＞@github.com/＜USER_NAME＞/＜REPOSITORY＞/raw/master/＜FILE_NAME＞`

全てダメでした orz

cubick♦さんのコメントいただいた情報をもとに実行したところ

`wget --header="Authorization: token ${TOKEN}" https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${USER_NAME}/${REPOSITORY}/master/${FILE}`

wget で取得できました。
ありがとうございます。

しかし、URLで表現しないとhtmlのヘッダでソースダウンロード用に使えませんので、URL だけで表現する方法を引き続き探しています。

ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願いいたします。

## 環境

Windows 10 開発端末
Raspberry Pi 3 
 node-red
 mosquitto

node-redの自前ノードを作成しています。（他のノードと連動するhttpノードの開発）  
外部と遮断された家内でのオレオレスマートホームを作成中です。

Comment: 参考: 英語版SOでの類似質問 - [How can I download a single raw file from a private github repo using the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18126559/2322778)

Comment: 解決した場合には質問に含めてしまうのではなく、ぜひ**個別の回答**として投稿してください (自己回答も歓迎されます)。

Comment: @cubick 「URLで表現しないと使えませんので、URL だけで表現する方法を模索しています。」とあるので解決していないのでは？、ただ分かりづらいのは確かなので質問を見直していただけると良いですね。

Comment: [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2701/xy-%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)に見えます。よっぽど特殊な環境でもない限り、開発している端末でWebアプリを動かして動作検証するほうが適切かと存じます。

Comment: とはいえ、GitHub or BitBucketのプライベートリポジトリから認証なしでJavascriptをHTMLからロードする方法、という技術的な興味はありますね

Comment: おっしゃる通り端末で動作検証するのが適切だと思います。  環境を付け加えました。 「GitHub or BitBucketのプライベートリポジトリから認証なしでJavascriptをHTMLからロードする方法」が必須事項でわけではありませんので一手間かければ代替で回避できます。    ただ自前npmモジュールをpackege.jsonのURL付け加えだけで簡単にgithubプライベートからインストールできたので、もしかしてHTMLヘッダからのダウンロードもできるのではとの軽い思いで調べ始めました。

Comment: XY問題、初めて知りました。そこに落ち込んでいそうな気がします orz

Comment: 「プライベート」リポジトリは必須ですか？不特定多数からアクセスされることを想定しているなら、トリッキーな方法に頼るより公開リポジトリの利用を検討すべきかと思います。

Comment: 因みにnode.jsオレオレモジュールをnpmを使用してgithubプライベートリポジトリからインストールするためにpackage.jsonのdependencies:に追加したのは「 "node-red-contrib-my-tasmota": "git+https://${TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/${USER_NAME}/node-red-contrib-my-tasmota.git", 」です。

Comment: 他の方が作成したMITライセンスのコードを自前仕様に変更して使っております。ライセンス上は公開してよさそうなのですが初心者が修正した誰にも役立たない汚いコードを公開することに躊躇してプライベートにしております。技術的に無理なら今行っている SSHFS でRaspberry Pi に送ります。

Comment: 自前のサーバが無い……というのが一番ネックな気はしますが、公開リポジトリにするか、サーバで自動同期するか、`PHP`などでソースコード取ってきて展開し、スクリプトとして読み込むとかでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node-red用の自作 node-red-contrib を npm に公開せずにプライベートリポジトリからインストールする方法を見つけてソース変更を簡単にターゲット端末に反映することができるようになり快適でした。
そこで HTML の src 指定でのダウンロードもプライベートリポジトリからできるかも、と軽い気持ちで調べ始めた次第です。

様々な方からアドバイスを頂きながら調べましたが重要事項でもない`実際の問題`ではなく、自分で考えた`解決法`を求めようとする（XY問題！？）のご指摘を受け、まさにその通りとうなずいてしまいました（開発中に直面した疑問や不思議を目にするといつの間にか本題とは関係ない方向へ進む癖があります orz）

自身への回答は
package.json を変更して node_modules に npm install で出来るようにしてソース修正では npm update で反映させるようにしました。
HTML の src で相対参照することにより問題解決といたしました。

```
package.json

・・・・
"dependencies": {
    "my-modules": "git+https://${TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/${USER_NAME}/my-modules.git", 
}
```

技術的に「GitHub or BitBucketのプライベートリポジトリから認証なしでJavascriptをHTMLからロードする方法」があるのかは不明です・・・

ありがとうございました。